# Using task list values as variables

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

How to use task list command in batch file and use results as variables.
For example, close chrome.exe if it is open

This is my experiment;

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('tasklist') do (
)
if "%%a"=="chrome.exe" (taskkill /f /im chrome.exe)
exit
```

please help but can't succeed

Comment: Your batch iterates tasklist output line by line and then does nothing with it : empty pair of parentheses. Outside the scope of the for command (same line/or code block) the variable `%%a` is invalid. See `tasklist /?`  or view [online](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)

Comment: First of all, my English is not very good. What I want to do is use the tasklist results as variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should develop your batch step by step, starting in an open cmd window.

```
C:\> tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
chrome.exe                   21416 Console                    1    125.716 K
chrome.exe                   20268 Console                    1      6.920 K
...
```

To process this sample output with a `for /f` you will have to first eliminate irrelevant lines
by filtering with a findstr or with an if.

```
C:\> tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" | findstr /ic:"chrome.exe"
chrome.exe                   21416 Console                    1    121.224 K
chrome.exe                   20268 Console                    1      6.920 K
```

`for /f` uses by default space/tab as delimiters and only token=1.
As we need the PID which is the 2nd token:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" ^| findstr /ic:"chrome.exe"
') Do echo %%a
```

Returns the bar PID numbers you are after.

```
21416
20268
```

Just don't echo but use `taskkill /PID %%a` to remove all chrome.exe processes.

The if variant:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"') Do (
    if /i "%%a"=="chrome.exe" taskkill /PID %%b
)
```

Comment: So how can I use it with IF ELSE

Comment: See appendum to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, man, that was exactly what I was looking for.